# How to test a returned array contains at least one value with a certain property value

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing

say I have a method I wish to test:

```
public Cars[] GetCars();
```

I want to test that the array returned by this method contains at least one car which is of type "Mustang".

How would I actually do this?

Currently I have code like:

```
[Test]
public void GetCars_ReturnsMustangs()
{
   Cars[] cars = GetCars();

   foreach(Car car in cars)
   {
      Assert.IsTrue(Car.Type == "Mustang");
   }
}
```

While this works as a test as far as I can tell I'm aware it's not a good idea to put loops inside the test?

Can anybody suggest a better alternative?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick, just be sure to add "using System.Linq;"

```
[Test]
public void GetCars_ReturnsMustangs()
{
    Cars[] cars = GetCars();
    Assert.IsTrue(cars.Where(c => c.Type == "Mustang").Count() > 0);
}
```

(That code hasn't been tested for syntax errors but should work fine)

**Edit:** Replace `.Count() > 0` with `.Any()` per @John's comment

Comment: . Using Any() instead of Count would probably be better.  See this reference http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/04/21/38598/

Comment: @John - Thanks, I didn't know about .Any() until you mentioned it.  Feels like I'm learning something new about LINQ every day haha

Answer (score 4):

Would Linq be an Option

```
using System.Linq

[Test]
public void GetCars_ReturnsMustangs()
{
   Cars[] cars = GetCars();
   Assert.IsTrue(cars.Any(c => c.Type == "Mustang"));
}
```

**Edited:**

Here is a great article on when to use Count() vs when to use Any()

http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/04/21/38598/

Answer (score 3):

What about:

```
Assert.IsTrue(cars.Any(c => c.Type == "Mustang"));
```

Answer (score 1):

With [**Gallio/MbUnit**](http://gallio.org) you can use [`Assert.Exists`](http://gallio.org/wiki/doku.php?id=mbunit%3aassertions%3acollection#assertexists):

```
Assert.Exists(cars, x => x.Type == "Mustang");
```